# Wordpress and AWS CloudFront (Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.)

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, amazon-web-services

I have been migrating a website from classic hosting to AWS (EC2 + CloudFront) and I would like to use Flexible-SSL which means that client (browser) use SSL(HTTPS) to comunicate with CloudFront, and CloudFront calls to the origin using HTTP unsecurely. Then is needed to set 'home' and 'siteurl' with 'https://www.myowndomain.com' in order to generate all URLs with https and avoid a redirections loop.

The first problem was the mixed content. I solved it using this code in *wp-config.php* (To help someone who needs it):

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLOUDFRONT_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_CLOUDFRONT_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https'){
    $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
}
```

The second problem is still unresolved and is taking me too many days...

When I go to wp-login and I do the login... the page respond me with:

> 403  - Sorry you are not allowed to access this page

If I go back to the home page, the website with menu bar is shown, but when I click on one option, It responds me again with the same message (and HTTP Status).

Things I have done before coming here:

- Disable all plugins, doing rename to all the plugins folders.
- Disable plugins using wp-cli.
- Search and replace all "http://" strings to "https://" using wp-cli in database.
- Check that *home* and *siteurl* wordpress variables are 'https://www.myowndomain.com'.
- Change the theme to default.
- Reload/remove the .htaccess
- Enable wordpress logs and nothing logged.
- Check all permissions, apparently all ok.
- Check database tables prefix configuration.
- Check all headers using the forensic module in Apache server-side. Some CloudFront headers added to the request but aparently nothing which could influence the issue.
- Check that all the cookies needed by wordpress were sent by the browser and received by the Apache server through CloudFront: *wordpress_logged_in_ and wordpress_sec_*.
- Debug a little bit adding some check points to the code... but I'm not wordpress developer and it costs me a lot to understand why this is happening. The 403 page is being triggered from */var/www/html/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php* in function *get_admin_page_parent()*.
- Clean browser cache again and again.
- Obviously search again and again.

What a mess! The last measure I took was to do a fresh-clean wordpress installation. The result... the same.

I'm stuck now. Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1) In CloudFront Behaviors for your distribution, enable "Redirect HTTP to HTTPS".

2) You will need to add the following code to your wp-config.php.

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
{
       $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}

if ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) )
{
        $ips = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);

        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = trim($ips[0]);
}
elseif ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']) )
{
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'];
} elseif ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) )
{
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you John,

Firstly, comment that CloudFront is configured as passthrough. Everywhing you request or send from browser is forwarded to Origin.

On the other han, I have done what you told me and the result is:

1. The mixed-content has came back.
2. When I go to wp-admin the browser goes to redirection loop.

Comment: Here you are the variable values after and before your code execution:


Configuracion before:
`HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR 78.9.73.148
REMOTE_ADDR 216.133.41.75
HTTP_X_REAL_IP (empty)
REMOTE_ADDR 216.133.41.75
HTTP_CLIENT_IP (empty)`

Configuracion after:
`HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR 78.9.73.148
REMOTE_ADDR 78.9.73.148
HTTP_X_REAL_IP (empty)
REMOTE_ADDR 78.9.73.148
HTTP_CLIENT_IP (empty)`

Answer (score 0):

Do this checklist:

**First**, confirm you have the following in your wp-config.php

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com' );
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
           $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

**Second**, confirm you are passing at least the `Host` and `Origin` headers to the origin.

**Third**, confirm you have these Cloudfront Cache behaviors with this configuration:

[image]

Reference: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/startups/how-to-accelerate-your-wordpress-site-with-amazon-cloudfront/